# Passing Controller Action output as SupplyData in UseSpaPrerendering of .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

In .Net Core application, I have below code in `Configure` method of **Startup.cs** file.

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {    
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
                {
                    options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/main.js";
                    options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment() ? new AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr") : null;
                    options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };
                });

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

`UseSpaPrerendering` has an option to provide `SupplyData` callback which lets you pass arbitrary, per-request, JSON-serializable data.

In my case there are pages in my Angular application which makes http requests to fetch data. Since these requests are made to the same application. I see a potential of optimization i.e. if we could just call the corresponding Controller Action method and supply its data to Angular, so that we dont have to make an http request for SSR.

Can anyone please guide how to achieve this.

I know that below is how we pass data using SupplyData

```
options.SupplyData = (context, data) =>
{
    // Creates a new value called isHttpsRequest that's passed to TypeScript code
    data["isHttpsRequest"] = context.Request.IsHttps;
};
```

But how to we pass the results/output of a Controller Actions (which returns json).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package to determine the currently activated SPA route from the supplydata delegate.

https://github.com/MusicDemons/AspNetSpaPrerendering

You have to define all your SPA routes using the SpaRouteBuilder and then you can check which route was activated and get the route data (like an id). Based on that you get data from your database through your repositories and add this data to the array. A complete example is included.